# Averaging Coordinates gives weird results

Tags: c#, location, average

I tried to implement a function that gives me an average from a list of locations represented through latitude and longitude values (as degrees). The old version of the function simply averaged these two values:

```
public static void CalculateMedianLocation(IEnumerable<GeographyPoint> locations, out Double latitude, out Double longitude)
{
    Double totalLatitude = 0;
    Double totalLongitude = 0;
    var count = 0;
    foreach (var location in locations)
    {
        totalLatitude += location.Latitude;
        totalLongitude += location.Longitude;
        count++;
    }
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    latitude= totalLatitude / count;
    longitude = totalLongitude / count;
}
```

However, this isn't really a good way to do this, because of possible resulting distortions. Based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7566) to a similar question I tried to change this to a better approach using cartesian coordinates averaging:

```
private static Vector3 DegreesToVector(Double latitude, Double longitude)
{
    var latitudeRadians = latitude.ToRadians();
    var longitudeRadians = longitude.ToRadians();
    var x = Math.Sin(latitudeRadians) * Math.Cos(longitudeRadians);
    var y = Math.Sin(latitudeRadians) * Math.Sin(longitudeRadians);
    var z = Math.Cos(latitudeRadians);
    return new Vector3(x, y, z);
}

private static void VectorToDegrees(Vector3 vector, out Double latitude, out Double longitude)
{
    latitude = Math.Atan2(vector.Z, Math.Sqrt(vector.X * vector.X + vector.Y * vector.Y)).ToDegrees();
    longitude = Math.Atan2(-vector.Y, vector.X).ToDegrees();
}

public static void CalculateMedianLocation(IEnumerable<GeographyPoint> locations, out Double latitude, out Double longitude)
{
    var total = new Vector3();
    var count = 0;
    foreach (var location in locations)
    {
        total += DegreesToVector(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
        count++;
    }
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    VectorToDegrees(total / count, out latitude, out longitude);
}
```

This, however, is giving me totally wrong values and I don't understand why. I checked the mathematics this solution is based on, and it seems everything is correct. What am I missing?

EDIT: I use the Vector3 implementation from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17425/A-Vector-Type-for-C) and the Extensions `ToDegrees()` and `ToRadians()` are implemented like this:

```
public static Double ToRadians(this Double val)
{
    return (Math.PI / 180.0) * val;
}

public static Double ToDegrees(this Double val)
{
    return val * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

Neither of those should be the cause of this problem.